# Update previous state object in HTML5 History

Tags: javascript, html5-history

In HTML5 History we have the `replaceState()` method to update the state object of the current history entry.

Do we have something like `previousState()` to update the state object of the previous history entry?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use history.back() or history.go() for it. And then you can use replaceState() for new current item from history. replaceState() is not used for previous history.